# gnupg not found

Tags: homebrew, gpg, rvm

I am trying to install [rvm](http://rvm.io). But I don't have gnupg/gpg installed. So I tried to install it using brew:

`brew install gnupg`

But after it's installed (verified by brew list), I cannot use gnupg.

`which gnupg` yields:

> gnupg not found

I have also tried using the direct binary path:

`/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.16_1 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

In which case, I get the following error:

> zsh: permission denied: /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.16_1

Comment: Hmm, `brew rm ` both the gnu and then the rvm might get you a proper error from the rvm install.

Comment: Output: Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.9.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.

[Removed gnupg. Installed rvm without gpg. `rvm -v` shows the version number. No trouble so far.]

Answer (score 4):

The command is `gpg`, not `gnupg` (gnupg is the package name)

```
$ brew install gnupg
...
...
$ which gpg
/usr/local/bin/gpg

$ gpg --version                                                   130
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.16
...
```

To install RVM,

```
$ gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
...
...
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```